# KStreams - countless logs of "Committing task offsets {}"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've upgraded KStreams from version 2.1.0 --> 2.7.0, and started to get the following log line, about 50-100 time a second:

> INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.TaskManager.commitOffsetsOrTransaction - stream-thread [app29-47331d9c-289a-436f-a609-06e0b430f555-StreamThread-2] **Committing task offsets {}**

Has anyone had the same problem, or know why does it happen?

Comment: It's not a problem unless the same offsets are repeated or the numbers go backwards... You upgraded many versions, and more log statements were added for debugging purposes

Comment: The problem is it floods my logs :). 50-100 times/sec is probably too much.. But I guess it is by design....

Comment: You can modify your log4j properties to exclude `o.a.k.s.p.internals.TaskManager` class